# Looping through directory containing csv files to perform operation

Tags: python, loops, csv

2 Daily files are placed in a folder, format being Items_20190102 and Items_20190102_orig.

I would like to pull the file via a loop without the 'orig' ending and perform aggregation using groupby on item level.

I would like to tally the daily aggregates into a monthly running total so as to produce a monthly dashboard throughout the year.

So far i have been able to group the data at item level and then compute running total for the day, on three summarized totals.

1. Uncalibrated spend
2. Calibrated spend.
3. Total Spend

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['Umbrella', 'Umbrella']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/2011'], 
                   'Product':['Umbrella', 'Umbrella', 'Badminton', 'Shuttle'], 
                   'Last Price':[1200, 1500, 1600, 352], 
                   'Updated Price':[1250, 1450, 1550, 400], 
                   'Discount':[10, 10, 10, 10]}) 

Uncalibrated = df[df['Product'].isin(l)].groupby('Product')['Last Price'].sum() 
Uncalibrated_abs = abs(uncalibrated)
Uncalibrated spend = Uncalibrated_abs.sum()
Calibrated = df[~df['Product'].isin(l)].groupby('Product')['Last Price'].tail(1)
Calibrated_Abs = abs(Calibrated)
Calibrated spend = Calibrated_Abs.sum()
Total = df.groupby(['Product'])['Last Price'].sum() 
Total_Spend = abs(Total).sum()
```

The result of this code will be in the form of three summarized statistics:

1. Uncalibrated_Spend.
2. Calibrated Spend.
3. Total Spend.

Now, i would like to generate a **loop** so that every day that this code runs it **appends the three statsitcs generated from that daily file** to a new column with a date as header and also generates a running total for the month on another column.

Output

```
                          26/06/2019 27/06/2016 Cum Monthly Total
```

1. Uncalibrated_Spend.        xxxxxx          xxxx            xxxx
2. Calibrated Spend.          xxxxxx          xxxx            xxxx
3. Total Spend.               xxxxxx          xxxx            xxxx

Comment: So you just want to append a column to a CSV? What does all this code have to do with that?

Comment: No thats not what I want to do. I want to loop through directory and then perform the calculations above for each file and append the statistics each day to a column on a new dataframe.

Comment: OK. What's your question then? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: You wrote what you want. You didn’t write what is your question.

Comment: How do i do it!?